# Store generated primary key in temp variable db2

Tags: sql, db2, udb

I'm in the process of writing batch loading SQL script and I would like to store the generated primary key of an insert statement into a temp variable and use it to reference the foreign key in the other tables. Any ideas?

I'm doing the following:

```
Y = INSERT INTO X(.....)

INSERT INTO Z(...,Y,);
```

Comment: what is the actual SQL you are using? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Do you not have a unique natural key (unique key that is not the `id` auto-gen id)?  Also, unless you are processing line-by-line, you can only store one (or some limited number) id at a time that way (assuming your version of DB2 supports declaring variables) - this may be slow.  Other than that... look for _data-change-table-reference_, probably the `NEW TABLE(INSERT ....)` clause.

Answer (score -1):

I know in SQL Server you can do:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable ....
SELECT @Foo = @@IDENTITY

INSERT INTO SomeOtherTable(... fk_col ...) VALUES (... @foo ...)
```